# Calling a Google Drive SDK from Google App Script application

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-docs-api

i have been going around in circles here and have totally confused myself.  I need some help.

I am (trying to) writing an application for a client that in concept is simple.  he want a google write document with a button.  the google drive account has several folders, each shared with several people. when he drops a new file in one of the folders, he wants to be able to open this write file, this file is the template for his email.  he clicks the button, the system calls the changes service in the Google Drive SDK https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-changes, gets the list of files that have been added since the last time it was checked, then pull the list of people that the file has been shared with, and use the write file as a template to send that list of people an email saying their file is ready.

SO, easy enough, right?

I started by looking at the built in functions in the Google App Script API.  I found this method, https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_docslist#find in the DocsList class.  problem is the description for the query simply says "the query string".  So at first i tried the Drive SDK query parameters, which are

```
var files = DocsList.find("modifiedDate > 2012-12-20T12:00:00-08:00.");
```

it didn't work.  that leads me to believe it is a simple full text search on the content.  Thats not good enough.

That lead me into trying to call a Drive SDK method from within an App Script application.  Great, we need an OLap 2 authentication.  easy enough.  found the objects in the script reference and hit my wall.

Client ID and Client Secret.

you see, when i create what this really is, a service account, the olap control in apps script doesn't know how to handle the encrypted json and pass it back and forth.  Then when i tried to create and use an installed applications key, i get authentication errors because the controls again, don't know what to do with the workflow.  and finally, when i try to create a web app key, i can't because i don't have the site host name or redirect URI.  And i can't use the application key ability because since im working with files OLap 2 is required.

i used the anonymous olap for a while, but hit the limit of anonymous calls per day in the effort of trying to figure out the code a bit, thats not going to work because the guy is going to be pushing this button constantly thru the day.

i have been pounding my head on the desk over this for 5 hours now.  i need some help here, can anyone give me a direction to go?

PS, yes, i know i can use the database controls and load the entire list of files into memory and compare it to the list of files in the database.  problem being, we are talking tens of thousands of files.  bad idea.

Comment: I don't believe it.  I just figured it out.  I created a web application client code, with https://google.com as the javascript originator and left the redirect blank and it worked.  go figure.

Comment: A search string that works is `var files = DocsList.find('after:2013-04-06T01:14');`

Comment: when i generate a "Client ID for web applications" and then try to enter google.com as "Authorized JavaScript Origins", the answer is : PostMessage Origin "google.com" is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use DocsList anymore - DriveApp is supposed to be a [more reliable replacement](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2115#c43). Some of the commands have changed, so instead of find, use [searchFiles](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#searchFiles%28String%29). This should work more effectively (they even use a query like yours as an example).